# Find $\frac{d x}{d y_0}$ of $x'=xy+t^2,y'=\frac{-y^2}{2}$ for $x_0=3$ and $y_0=2$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

We've got:
$x' = xy +t^2$, $y' = \frac{-y^2}{2}$, $x(1)=x_0$,$y(1)=y_0$.
My task is to find $\frac{d x}{d y_0}$ for $x_0 = 3$ and $y_0 = 2$.

I computed $y$ for $y_0=2$ and so we have $y(t) = \frac{2}{t}$, hence $x' = x \cdot \frac{t}{2} + t^2$.
But how to find $\frac{d x}{d y_0}$? I know how to find $\frac{d x}{d x_0}$, having a certain theorem, but it's not the question... Can anybody help?

Answer (score 1):

Like you said, you have:
$$
\frac{dx}{dt} = x\frac{2}{t} + t^2,
$$
Then by chain rule
$$
\frac{dx}{dy} = \frac{dx}{dt} \frac{dt}{dy}, 
$$
plugging numbers:
$$
\frac{dx}{dy}\Big|_{y=y_0} = \frac{dx}{dt}\Big|_{t= y^{-1}(y_0)}\cdot  
\frac{dt}{dy}\Big|_{y=y_0} = \frac{dx}{dt}\Big|_{t= y^{-1}(y_0)}\cdot  
\left(\frac{dy}{dt}\right)^{-1}\Big|_{ t= y^{-1}(y_0)} . 
$$
When $y= y_0 = 2$, $t = y^{-1}(y_0) = 1$, thus $x = x_0 = 1$, above reads:
$$
\frac{dx}{dy}\Big|_{y=2} = \left(\frac{2x}{t} + t^2\right)\cdot  \left(-\frac{y^2}{2}\right)^{-1}\Bigg|_{x=1,y=2,t=1}.
$$